# gradle configuration to download custom plugin dependencies

Tags: maven, gradle

I created a gradle plugin (short named as testinfra), which has compile time and runtime dependency on 2 other jars.  Here is my build.gradle for my plugin:

```
/**
 * Define the dependencies for compiling the plugin code
 */
dependencies {
    compile gradleApi()
    compile localGroovy()
    compile group:'com.mycompany.tools', name: 'lrgmanager', version: '1.0+'
    compile group: 'com.mycompany.tools', name: 'LrgParser', version: '1.0+'
}


/**
 * This task is responsible for publishing the plugin jar in the artifactory
 */ 
group   = 'com.mycompany.tools'  
version = '1.0'
publishing {
    publications {
        publishPlugin(MavenPublication) {
            artifact jar
        }
    }
}
```

I am able to push my plugin jar to artifactory. But when I want to use the plugin, I have to specify the GAV of my plugin and also its dependencies. See below:

```
/**
 * define classpath for buildscript{}, to download the regression plugin and its dependencies
 */
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'com.mycompany.tools', name: 'testinfra', version: '1.0+'
        classpath group:'com.mycompany.tools', name: 'lrgmanager', version: '1.0+'
        classpath group: 'com.mycompany.tools', name: 'LrgParser', version: '1.0+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'testinfra'
```

My requirement is to avoid specifying the dependent jar's GAV along with the testinfra plugin GAV. Is there a way where I can configure my pom.xml (publish task) during publish such that when I specify GAV of my plugin, gradle identifies the dependencies and downloads them as well ?

I tried to reference the gradle user guide for this but I don't see any clear example for this.

Comment: I suppose You should use `maven` plugin and configure `uploadArchives` task appropriately. Are You using it? See here: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html

Comment: I'm using 'maven-publish' plugin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `artifact jar`, use `from components.java`. Then the dependencies should appear in the POM, and Gradle will pull them in automatically.

Comment: This is groovy code. Do I still need to say components.java or I have to say components.groovy ?

Comment: Use `components.java`. There is no `components.groovy`.

Comment: adding components.java to my plugin's build.gradle did not work. Here is the pom.xml which is generated (which is same as it was earlier)
`
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.oracle.emaas.emdi</groupId>
  <artifactId>testinfra</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
</project>`

Comment: Chances are that something is wrong with your build then. Check the *maven-publish* plugin chapter in the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html) for details. Note that it's `from components.java`, not `components.java`.

Comment: Yes I was using `components.java`. When I used `from components.java` it worked. But now it is failing because the dependencies of the plugin dependencies are not pulled.

i.e., testinfra dependsOn lrgmanager 
and lrgManager dependsOn groovy:2.3

I modified the code of both lrgManager's build.gradle and testinfra build.gradle to use `from components.java`
and I see lrgmanager's pom has dependency entry for groovy. And testinfra's pom has dependency entry for lrgparser and lrgmanager.

what should I do to get the groovy:2.3 as well ?

Comment: Groovy should never be pulled in for a Gradle plugin. It's provided by Gradle.

Comment: Ok I used `compile localGroovy()` in lrgmanager's build.gradle; So no download of groovy anymore.
I still get this excption:

`Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/typehandling/ShortTypeHandling`

Comment: This should be a new question. (I already answered it here: http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/gradle_1_x_and_2_x_compatible_plugins)

Comment: Ok, thanks. Posted my query here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24756539/noclassdeffound-shorttypehandling-with-gradle-custom-plugin-usage

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser: related question - if the maven repo that the custom plugin comes from is different from the repo that the dependency comes from, is there any way to avoid requiring the user of the custom plugin from having to add the dependency's maven repo to its `buildscript` block?